# Identifier 'EmailEditorProps' has already been declared

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I tried to excute this github React email editor in my local.
github url is [react-email-editor](https://github.com/unlayer/react-email-editor)
but it doesn't excute properly.[image: this is screenshot on my local when i run the script.]